# PhotoView with Picasso: Some images appears smaller on listview

Tags: android, listview, android-imageview, zooming

I am using [PhotoView](https://github.com/chrisbanes/PhotoView) with [Picasso](http://square.github.io/picasso/) and when I load images into `ListView`

1) It makes some images smaller.

2) not all  images are loaded on launch, when i scroll down an then up then all the images are loaded.

Without `PhotoView` images loads just fine. I tried so many `ImageView` zooming libraries but `PhotoView` works better and I have also tried it with [Glide](https://github.com/bumptech/glide) the result is same.

Is there anyway I could force `PhotoView` to fit to `ImageView` attributes (which are `Match_Parent`)?

Here is my Adapter

```
@Override
public void onBindViewHolder( final ViewHolder holder, int position) {

    Picasso.with(context)
            .load((Integer) data.get(position))
            .resize(530,999)
            .onlyScaleDown()
            .centerInside()
            .into(holder.image);

    holder.mAttacher = new PhotoViewAttacher(holder.image);

    holder.image.setTag(holder);

}

@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return data.size();
}

public class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

    public PhotoView image;
    public PhotoViewAttacher mAttacher;

    public ViewHolder(View view) {
        super(view);
        image = (PhotoView) view.findViewById(R.id.imagview);
```

**I am loading images from resources/drawable not from any `url`**

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, there is an issue at Picasso, more details at [issue #364](https://github.com/square/picasso/issues/364)

I switched to another library [Glide](https://github.com/bumptech/glide)

Comment: [issue 754](https://github.com/square/picasso/issues/754) additional reason to switch to another library

Comment: regarding picasso , did you face memory problems ?

Comment: @Moudiz what kind of problem? please clarify you question

Comment: @gio I am getting this error when using `Glide` `java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: You must not call setTag() on a view Glide is targeting`

Comment: @Anders remove `holder.image.setTag(holder);`

Comment: @gio result is same as picasso, alot of padding between images too.

Comment: @Anders replace `.centerInside()` by `.centerCrop()`

Comment: @gio  better but it messes up the small images in the list by zooming them?

Comment: not sure, that zooming at is good idea, zoom/pan will conflict with scroll of list,

Comment: its fine, it doesn't conflict much, the problem only comes with photoview, but there is no other library that works any good for zooming

Answer (score 0):

You can change your attacher scale type:

```
holder.mAttacher = new PhotoViewAttacher(holder.image);
holder.mAttacher.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.CENTER_CROP);
```

> **CENTER_CROP**: Scale the image uniformly (maintain the image's aspect ratio) so that
>   both dimensions (width and height) of the image will be equal to or
>   larger than the corresponding dimension of the view (minus padding).
>   The image is then centered in the view.

Comment: it still same, no luck, the result is almost same with both `Glide` and `Picasso` without `PhotoView` they both works fine

Comment: Even with *FIT_XY* ?

Comment: FIT_XY Align the images right but the gap between images would not go, i loved `PhotoView` but because of this bug i can't use it

Comment: What do you mean by "the gap between images" ? can you add a screenshot?

Comment: means images are not not aligned in list, some images appear smaller and it creates gap between images and wen ill double tap it to zoom then it will fill the gap.

Comment: Try to change your attacher scale range, exp: *mAttacher.setMinimumScale(1.0f);* , *mAttacher.setMediumScale(1.5f);* and *mAttacher.setMaximumScale(2.0f);*

Comment: by changing scale range, images are fitting perfect except the few with lower resolution but the gap is still there, like if we scroll image list there will be few images missing in between and if we scroll upward again then they might appear in the list